# How to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage on Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, boto, google-cloud-platform

How can I upload a file to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) from Python 3? Eventually Python 2, if it's infeasible from Python 3.

I've looked and looked, but haven't found a solution that actually works. I tried [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto), but when I try to generate the necessary .boto file through `gsutil config -e`, it keeps saying that I need to configure authentication through `gcloud auth login`. However, I have done the latter a number of times, without it helping.

Comment: The gcloud bundle uses its own auth mechanism that shares credentials amongst all its bundled CLIs.  To configure a .boto file like this, you'll need to use the standalone install of gsutil.  That being said, I'm not confident that the gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin module supports Python 3 (yet).  So you may need to do your own port of that module, or the pieces of it that you need, to Python 3.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Use the standard [gcloud](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python#google-cloud-python-client) library, which supports both Python 2 and Python 3.

### Example of Uploading File to Cloud Storage

```
from gcloud import storage
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import os


credentials_dict = {
    'type': 'service_account',
    'client_id': os.environ['BACKUP_CLIENT_ID'],
    'client_email': os.environ['BACKUP_CLIENT_EMAIL'],
    'private_key_id': os.environ['BACKUP_PRIVATE_KEY_ID'],
    'private_key': os.environ['BACKUP_PRIVATE_KEY'],
}
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(
    credentials_dict
)
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project='myproject')
bucket = client.get_bucket('mybucket')
blob = bucket.blob('myfile')
blob.upload_from_filename('myfile')
```

Comment: oh my lord, thank you so much.  I've been looking for something simple to describe how to connect to the system.  there's no "authentication" teachings around.  This is great!  Thanks

Comment: Please note `oauth2client` is deprecated. https://github.com/google/oauth2client. 
Also, in the newer versions of google cloud python packages, use `from google.cloud import storage` instead of `from gcloud...`

Comment: If you can't `.get_bucket` because you have limited permission to the storage, you can use `.bucket` instead. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample

Comment: I wonder why googles documentation of buckets (https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/buckets.html) does not include such crucial examples...

Comment: @Shiva are you aware of an example of this answer which would be considered up to date?

Comment: @baxx The other answer by adam is up to date.

Comment: I have opened a new thread on similar area : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66290048/cx-freeze-module-for-google-cloud-programs-in-python . Can somebody please let me know how do we deal with this ?

Answer (score 84):

A simple function to upload files to a gcloud bucket.

```
from google.cloud import storage
#pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage. 
def upload_to_bucket(blob_name, path_to_file, bucket_name):
    """ Upload data to a bucket"""
     
    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'creds.json')

    #print(buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())

    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(path_to_file)
    
    #returns a public url
    return blob.public_url
```

You can generate a credential file using this link: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries?authuser=1#client-libraries-install-python

Asynchronous Example:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
# pip install aiofile
from aiofile import AIOFile
# pip install gcloud-aio-storage
from gcloud.aio.storage import Storage 

BUCKET_NAME = '<bucket_name>'
FILE_NAME  = 'requirements.txt'
async def async_upload_to_bucket(blob_name, file_obj, folder='uploads'):
    """ Upload csv files to bucket. """
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        storage = Storage(service_file='./creds.json', session=session) 
        status = await storage.upload(BUCKET_NAME, f'{folder}/{blob_name}', file_obj)
        #info of the uploaded file
        # print(status)
        return status['selfLink']
        

async def main():
    async with AIOFile(FILE_NAME, mode='r') as afp:
        f = await afp.read()
        url = await async_upload_to_bucket(FILE_NAME, f)
        print(url)


# Python 3.6
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

# Python 3.7+
# asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Is this method synchronous?

Comment: @DJ319 I have also added asynchronous example

Comment: I have opened a new thread on similar area : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66290048/cx-freeze-module-for-google-cloud-programs-in-python . Can somebody please let me know how do we deal with this ?

Answer (score 27):

Imports the Google Cloud client library (need [credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-python))

```
from google.cloud import storage
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:/Users/siva/Downloads/My First Project-e2d95d910f92.json"
```

Instantiates a client

```
storage_client = storage.Client()

buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("ad_documents") # your bucket name

blob = bucket.blob('chosen-path-to-object/{name-of-object}')
blob.upload_from_filename('D:/Download/02-06-53.pdf')
print(buckets)
```

Comment: I have opened a new thread on similar area : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66290048/cx-freeze-module-for-google-cloud-programs-in-python . Can somebody please let me know how do we deal with this ?

Answer (score 10):

When installing Google Cloud Storage API:

`pip install google-cloud`

will throw a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```sh
    from google.cloud import storage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

**Make sure you install as in** [Cloud Storage Client Libraries Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries):

`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`

Answer (score 0):

This official repo contains a handful of snippets demonstrating the different ways to upload a file to a bucket: https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/tree/05e07f248fc010d7a1b24109025e9230cb2a7259/samples/snippets

- `upload_from_string()`
- `upload_from_file()`
- `upload_from_filename()`