# Writing data to google cloud storage using python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I cannot find a way to to write a data set from my local machine into the google cloud storage using python. I have researched a a lot but didn't find any clue regarding this. Need help, thanks

Comment: did you ever found a way? it seems people tends to confuse the upload with an actual write

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage on Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003862/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-cloud-storage-on-python-3)

Answer (score 18):

Quick example, using the [google-cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) Python library:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
  """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
  storage_client = storage.Client()
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
  blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

  blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

  print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
      source_file_name,
      destination_blob_name))
```

More examples are in this GitHub repo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/cloud-client

Comment: What do you mean by a write?

Comment: base on this link https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage (from what I understood) this will allow you to create the file in the bucket, instead of uploading

Comment: Creating a file by specifying its contents is the same operation as uploading a new file. It's just called a different name here.

Comment: my bad, I though in the upload you create a file and then upload, in the other i though you actually create the file directly in the bucket folder, for hence never in your server, I am having issues as appengine doesnt allows me to create files so i am trying to find that solution

Answer (score 5):

When we want to write a string to a GCS bucket blob, the only change necessary is using `blob.upload_from_string(your_string)` rather than `blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)`:

```
from google.cloud import storage

def write_to_cloud(your_string):
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket123456789')
    blob = bucket.blob('PIM.txt')
    blob.upload_from_string(your_string)
```

Answer (score 4):

In the earlier answers, I still miss the easiest way, using the `open()` method.

You can use the `blob.open()` as follows:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
    
def write_file():
    client = storage.Client()
        bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-name')
        blob = bucket.blob('path/to/new-blob-name.txt') 
        ## Use bucket.get_blob('path/to/existing-blob-name.txt') to write to existing blobs
        with blob.open(mode='w') as f:
            for line in object: 
                f.write(line)
```

You can find more examples and snippets here:
https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/tree/main/samples/snippets

Answer (score 3):

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
filename = 'file.csv'
bucket = 'Your bucket name here'
body = {'name': 'file.csv'}    
req = service.objects().insert(bucket=bucket, body=body, media_body=filename)
resp = req.execute()
```

Comment: that looks like an upload not a write?

Comment: @Manza isn't the same ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.cloud import storage

def write_to_cloud(buffer):
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket123456789')
    blob = bucket.blob('PIM.txt')
    blob.upload_from_file(buffer)
```

While [Brandon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43685299/6243352) indeed gets the file to Google cloud, it does this by uploading the file, as opposed to writing the file. This means that the file needs to exist on your disk before you upload it to the cloud.

My proposed solution uses an "in-memory" payload (the `buffer` parameter) which is then written to cloud. To write the content you need to use `upload_from_file` instead of `upload_from_filename`, everything else being the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
L = logging.getLogger(__name__)
from google.cloud import storage

def write_file(bucket_name, source_string, destination_blob_name):        
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    if not bucket.blob(destination_blob_name).exists():
        L.warn(f"Blob {destination_blob_name} does not exist.")
        print(f"Blob {destination_blob_name} does not exist.")
        print(f"Creating blob {destination_blob_name}.")
        blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    else:
        print(f"Blob {destination_blob_name} exists.")
    with blob.open(mode='w') as f:
        for line in source_string:
            f.write(line)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).