# How to access dataset on Google ML Cloud Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, cloud, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-datasets

How to access my local dataset on jupyter notebook on google ML cloud engine?

I have created a VM on Google ML Cloud engine and also installed anaconda on the same VM.

How to access public and private image dataset from jupyter notebook?

I have uploaded very small dataset using upload button on jupyter notebook. But for this I have to upload all images one by one.
Is there any way to just upload train and test dataset folders there?

How to access public dataset using a URL?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using `gsutil` that comes as part of the GCP SDK. This tool enables you to move local data to Google Cloud Storage so you can then access it through your notebooks.

Comment: Yes, I have created a bucket and uploaded directories and files on it. but how to read those files from jupyter ntebook ?

Comment: Have you tried the python Client Libraries from Jupyter?, e.g. [for reading](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-code_sample): 
   blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
for [writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43685299/9457843):
   blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name).

Another option that you may want to consider is [Deep Learning Virtual Machine](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/), and then [connect](https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter).