# Trying to upload a .wav file to a bucket using python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests, google-cloud-storage, python-3.7

I'm trying to upload a `.wav` file (lets say `test.wav`) into my google storage bucket but i'm running into some problems: A storage object gets uploaded with the appropriate 'test.wav' name, but inside it is just the data from my request. Also the `contentType` in the bucket is displayed as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

My bucket has public read/write/delete permissions and uploading other file types works fine. Uploading this way also works fine through postman.

```py
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/<bucket_name>/o"

payload ={
    "acl":"public-read",
    "file":open('test.wav'),
    "signature":signature,
    "policy":policy              
}
headers={"contentType":"audio/wav"}
params={"uploadType":"media","name":"test.wav"}
response = requests.post(url,data=payload,headers=headers,params=params)
print(response.text)
```

Currently I get the following error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 
4420: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've also tried `scipy.io.wavfile.read()` and `pydub.AudioSegment()` but these don't work for me either.

Ideally, I'd want the file to be successfully uploaded and usable for transcription through google's STT.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround to this problem. Instead of using the requests module, I've switched over to using the method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003862/google-cloud-storage-how-to-upload-a-file-from-python-3).

Doing this uploads the file properly, instead of its data being uploaded to a file with a `.wav` extension. Thereby fixing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the `uploadType` parameter to be `media`. That means that the body of the request is the body of the object you're uploading. However, you're specifying the body field of your POST to be a dictionary with fields like ""acl", "signature", and "file". It looks like maybe you're attempting a sort of form-style POST, but that's not how media uploads look.

Here's how you'd use Requests to do a media-style upload to GCS:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/<bucket_name>/o"

headers = {
    "acl": "public-read",
    "Authorization": "Bearer ...",
    "Content-Type": "audio/wav",
}
params = {"uploadType": "media", "name": "test.wav"}
with open('test.wav', 'rb') as file:
  r = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, data=file)
print(r.text)
```