# Python Gsutil Google SDK Shell

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

When i run commands from google sdk Shell, i got no error :

```
# login
gcloud auth login
# upload files to bucket : google cloud storage
gsutil cp "My_File_Path" gs://"My_Bucket_Name
```

When i run the same commands from windows cmd, i got error : `AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission`

I'm willing to run the commands from windows cmd so i can automate it easily on my python script using :

```
import os
os.system("gcloud auth login")
os.system("gsutil cp 'Path_To_File' gs://'Bucket_Name'")
```

**On windows cmd : os.system("gcloud auth login") runs without errors, second command get the error :**  `AccessDeniedException: 403 Insufficient Permission`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gcloud auth login` is generating a link that you have to follow to authenticate into Coud SDK. So it probably can be run without authentication error, as it only returns a link and is waiting for verification code. But running this `gsutil` needs authenticated Cloud SDK.

If you need to upload file using Python, I think that better way to use Python API. There is very nice [example](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-python) in Google documentation. If you want to setup Python API authentication you need to setup environment variables as explained in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries?authuser=1#windows).

Please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003862/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-cloud-storage-on-python-3) as well.