# How to upload & get custom metadata with gcloud-aio-storage?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using gcloud-aio-storage to cache a file. There is an option to add metadata dict in upload function

```
async def upload(self, bucket: str, object_name: str, file_data: Any,
                 *, content_type: Optional[str] = None,
                 parameters: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None,
                 headers: Optional[Dict[str, str]] = None,
                 metadata: Optional[Dict[str, Any]])
```

There is also a function to download metadata
`async def download_metadata(self, bucket: str, object_name: str,`

One should be able to add metadata and retrieve it later using the above functions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you wanted to upload an object with custom metadata and then retrieve it once needed.

The custom metadata won't be added if you pass your key-value pairs into `upload()` like this:

```
metadata_dict = {
  "foo" : "bar",
  "color": "green"
}
```

The reason is because the library is looking for the `metadata` key within the dictionary. See code snippet [here](https://github.com/talkiq/gcloud-aio/blob/master/storage/gcloud/aio/storage/storage.py#L496). I reviewed the library and in this case, the [request body](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert#request-body) becomes:

```
{"foo": "bar", "color": "green", "name": "filename.txt"}
```

Where the correct one must be:

```
{"metadata": {"foo": "bar", "color": "green"}, "name": "filename.txt"}
```

The solution is to configure your dictionary like this:

```
meta_dict = {
    "metadata":{
      "foo" : "bar",
      "color": "green"
    }
}
```

Full code example (credits to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52181711/7031308)):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
# pip install aiofile
from aiofile import AIOFile
# pip install gcloud-aio-storage
from gcloud.aio.storage import Storage 
import logging
import sys

BUCKET_NAME = 'BUCKET_NAME'
FILE_NAME  = 'FILE_NAME.txt'
meta_dict = {
    "metadata":{
      "foo" : "bar",
      "color": "green"
    }
}
async def async_upload_to_bucket(blob_name, file_obj, meta_dict):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        storage = Storage(session=session) 
        status = await storage.upload(BUCKET_NAME, blob_name, file_obj, metadata=meta_dict)
        print(status['metadata'])
        return status['selfLink']

async def main():
    async with AIOFile(FILE_NAME, mode='r') as afp:
        f = await afp.read()
        url = await async_upload_to_bucket(FILE_NAME, f, meta_dict)
        print(url)


# Python 3.7+
asyncio.run(main()) 
print("success")
```